# ApostropheCMS - Rendering a full HTML page in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

I created a new page(extends apostrophe-custom-pages) and created several POST-routes in it. They're named exactly like some other regular pages and should handle only the POST-requests.

This code works very well and renders the empty layout:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',
    afterConstruct: function (self) {
        self.apos.app.post('/xyz', self.handlePostRequest);
    },
    construct: function (self, options) {
        self.handlePostRequest = (req, res) => {
            // Do some stuff

            return self.sendPage(req, self.renderer('layout'), () => ({
                'success': false
            }));
        }
    }
};
```

Now i want to simply render the same page as it's delivered by a GET-request with some variables assigned to the view(e.g. "success" => false).

Answer (score 2):

`self.apos.app.get('foo', self.handleGetRequest);`

followed by:

```
self.handleGetRequest = (req, res) => {
  // Do some stuff
  return self.sendPage(req, self.renderer('layout'), { foo: 'bar' });
}
```

You'll then have `{{ data.foo }}` available in your `layout.html` file.